# C++: GetKeyState() has to run once

Tags: c++, winapi, keyboard, keypress

I need to listen keyboard key states for my tiny application.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    while(1)
    {
        if(GetKeyState(VK_SPACE) & 0x80)
        {
            cout << "Space pressed.\r\n";
            DoSpaceKeyTask();
        }

        if(GetKeyState(OTHER_KEY) & 0x80)
        {
            cout << "Other key pressed.\r\n";
            DoOtherKeyTask();
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Once I click some keys from my keyboard, these functions has to run once. They're just some tiny tasks for my applications, which is not related in this topic.

My problem is, when I press a key, it executes the functions few times, due to `while(1)` looping few times during key press. I cannot use `Sleep()` in this case, because it still won't be effective.

I'm looking for a solution like this.

1. I press SPACE key.
2. `DoSpaceKeyTask()` executes "once."
3. I press OTHER key.
4. `DoOtherKeyTask()` executes "once."

I have like 5 keys that I will be using. Could anyone help me on this case?

Ps. If `GetKeyState()` function isn't useful on this task, feel free to suggest yours. My function knowledge is pretty limited on C++.

Comment: 1. You want `GetAsyncKeyState` for that loop. 2. You have to mask it with `0x8000`. Also, you can use `while (GetAsyncKeyState(...) & 0x8000)` to wait for it to go up.

Comment: Here's a good blurb on point 1: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/11/30/272262.aspx

Comment: Hi chris, it is still the same with GetAsyncKeyState and 0x8000. Any ideas?

Comment: You should either use a state mechanism, as seen below, or use something that notifies you of key presses/depresses, like a window or a hook.

Comment: State mechanisms look hacky. How can I search for those window/hook on Google? What should I type in general? Also, my application will run on background, while the real application run on foreground. I just want to automate some tasks. Like if you've ever played a RPG game, I want to sell my whole inventory to NPC with a single key press.

Comment: DoSpaceKeyTask() function just has to click on each item in my inventory. (mouse click predefined coordinates quickly.) So yeah, I'm looking for a solution on this. I've used KeyState just because my Google searches showed it to me. I just want to get key states of keyboard, regardless of which application on foreground. I can close it when necessary.

Comment: Oh, that clears things up a bit better. The function you're looking for is `SetWindowsHookEx`. There are quite a few good examples of the various hooks, but the one you want is to hook the game window's message procedure. Hook it to check for key events, and handle them appropriately.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look at it right now. :)

Answer (score 5):

Your functions are called multiple times because of the duration time the button stays pressed. The system is very sensitive.  So this is a workaround.

You could do something like this (set a flag that will assign a value when the key is down, and then reasign it when the key is up).

```
int k=0;//Flag
while(1){
    //check if the key was pressed (key_down)
    if((GetAsyncKeyState('0') & 0x8000) && (k == 0)){k=1; cout<<"'0' PRESSED."<<k<<endl;}//do your stuff here
    //check if the key was released (key up)
    else if(GetAsyncKeyState('0') == 0) k = 0;//reset the flag
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that you will prefer to execute your functions "once" only when you have released up your keys, not when you have depressed (pressed) them down.

You don't need any additional flags and helper variables to define, allocate, assign to 0, and set each one to 1 and reset to 0 and so on, in order to achieve this goal. All what you need is just: First you have to use GetKeyState function inside the scope of while(1) to check when you have depressed a key. When the expression returns true, the executor pointer (the arrow that carry out a code line and then proceeds forward to the next code line when you either step into or step over) will enter into the if statement's scope. Then immediately trap it inside a loop and keep it trapped in there while the key you have depressed is still down and stop it before it is going to execute the function and free it when you have released that key up and then let it to execute the function.

For example, to execute the DoSpaceKeyTask function only "once" when you have depressed and released the space bar, then do the following code that should work:

```
while (1)
{
    if (GetKeyState(VK_SPACE) & 0x80)
    {
        //The code here executes ONCE at the moment the space bar was pressed
        cout << "Space pressed.\r\n";
        while (GetKeyState(VK_SPACE) & 0x80) //You can write there ';' instead '{' and '}' below
        {
            //The executor pointer is trapped here while space bar is depressed and it will be free once space bar is released
        }
        //The code here executes ONCE at the moment the space bar was released
        cout << "Space released.\r\n";
        DoSpaceKeyTask();
    }
}
```

Just the same with DoOtherKeyTask function:

```
while (1)
{
    if (GetKeyState(OTHER_KEY) & 0x80)
    {
        //The code here executes ONCE at the moment the other key was pressed
        cout << "Other key pressed.\r\n";
        while (GetKeyState(OTHER_KEY) & 0x80) //You can write there ';' instead '{' and '}' below
        {
            //The executor pointer is trapped here while other key is depressed and it will be free once other key is released
        }
        //The code here executes ONCE at the moment the other key was released
        cout << "Other key released.\r\n";
        DoOtherKeyTask();
    }
}
```

If you have already used either BT_'s idea or Pawel Zubrycki's idea, and now you want to use my idea, then you can delete all flags and variables that they suggested, because you don't need them anymore.

By the way, I have already tried the code that Pawel Zubrycki posted, but it doesn't work for me. The output that says that I have pressed either space bar or other key was not displayed when I have really pressed the space bar or other key that I chose.

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char lastSpaceState = 0, lastOtherKeyState = 0, spaceState, otherKeyState;
    while(1)
    {
        spaceState = (GetKeyState(VK_SPACE & 0x80) != 0);
        lastSpaceState = (spaceState && !lastSpaceState);
        if(lastSpaceState)
        {
                cout << "Space pressed.\r\n";
                DoSpaceKeyTask();
        }

        otherKeyState = (GetKeyState(OTHER_KEY) & 0x80 != 0);
        lastOtherKeyState = (otherKeyState && !lastOtherKeyState);
        if(lastOtherKeyState)
        {
                cout << "Other key pressed.\r\n";
                DoOtherKeyTask();
        }

    }

    return 0;
}
```

or as Chris suggest in OP comment more "modern" async approach.

Comment: It's not really a case of old or modern. `GetKeyState` is for messages when you need the state at the time the message was sent. `GetAsyncKeyState` is for the state right now. Also, 0x80 is 10000000. The documentation says the high bit will be set if it's down, and that it returns short, hence 1000000000000000, or 0x8000.

Comment: I appreciate your reply, but with 5 or more keys, it will be a complete mess.

Comment: @AnılÜnal, you can do almost the same thing using a hook. Something like (not real syntax): `if (WM_KEYDOWN) { switch (code) { case SPACE: if (last == UP) DoSomething(); ... } }` and set the state using `WM_KEYDOWN` and `WM_KEYUP` messages. A hook shouldn't get called until keyboard actions occur too; it should be idle otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

You want a windows hook to hook the game and react to the keyboard input that game gets. Now I haven't really done this specific type of hook, but I can give you a good idea of the flow. I'll leave it up to you to cut down the space by looping through a map of keys you need rather than a huge, repetitive switch, and also to work out any small kinks I put in.

```
int main()
{
    //I imagine the last argument here is the thread 
    //containing the game's message loop
    HHOOK hook = SetWindowsHookEx (WH_CALLWNDPROC, hookProc, NULL, NULL);

    //main loop

    UnhookWindowsHookEx (hook);
}

LRESULT CALLBACK hookProc (int code, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if (code == HC_ACTION)
    {
         CWPSTRUCT details = *((LPCWPSTRUCT)lParam);

         if (details.message == WM_KEYDOWN)
         {   
              switch (details.wParam)
              { 
                  case KEY_ONE:
                      if (last [KEY_ONE] == UP)
                      {
                          DoKeyOneStuff();
                          last [KEY_ONE] = DOWN;
                      }
                      break;
              }
          }

          else if (details.message == WM_KEYUP)
          {
              switch (details.wParam)
              {
                   case KEY_ONE:
                       last [KEY_ONE] = UP;
                   break;
              }
          }
    }

    return CallNextHookEx (NULL, code, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Note how I use `last [KEY_ONE]`. I would recommend using an `std::map` to store keys you need by their vk code. Then you can just loop through the map and cut down a lot of space that a switch would take.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue.  I have several keys that act like toggle buttons and only want to register the key events once per press.  My solution was to make a simple object to handle the logic.  This keeps the main code clean:

```
class KeyToggle {
public:
    KeyToggle(int key):mKey(key),mActive(false){}
    operator bool() {
        if(GetAsyncKeyState(mKey)){
            if (!mActive){
                mActive = true;
                return true;
            }  
        }
        else
            mActive = false;
        return false;
    }
private:
    int mKey;
    bool mActive;
};
```

And here is the usage:

```
#include <windows.h>

KeyToggle toggleT(0x54);  // T key toggle
KeyToggle toggleF(0x46);  // F key toggle

void main(void)
{
    while(true){
        if(toggleT) {;} // do something
        if(toggleF) {;} // do something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is pretty old thread but I still want to share my solution. I think that creating some kind of "flags" or "switches" is really not needed. Here is my code of looping all keycodes:

```
    while (true) 
    {
        for (int i = 0x01; i < 0xFE; i++) 
        {
            if (GetKeyState(i) & 0x8000)
            {
                std::cout << (char)i << "\n";
                while (GetKeyState(i) & 0x8000) {}
            }
        }
    }
```

As you can see, you can easily just use while and the same GetKeyState function to wait for the key unpress. Much simpler solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try sth. like this;

```
    while (!GetKeyState(VK_SPACE) && !GetKeyState('A') == 1) {
    //std::cout << "Key not pressed... \n";
    Sleep(40);
}
if (GetKeyState('A')) {
    std::cout << "\"A \" key pressed... \n";
}
else if (GetKeyState(VK_SPACE)) {
    std::cout << "Space key pressed... \n";
}
```